# ConcurrentSkipListMap and multi-column comparator

Tags: java

I have following class `KeyObj`

```
public class KeyObject {
    private byte[] P1;
    private byte[] P2;
    private byte[] P3;
}
```

I want to put the object of this class into `ConcurrentSkipListMap` I am confuse on how to write comparator so that range queries are possible. i.e. if `P1` is given then it return me `p2 and p3`. something like below

```
KeyObject fromKey = new KeyObject(K1.P1, P2_MIN_VALUE, P3_MIN_VALUE);
KeyObject toKey = new KeyObject(K2.P1, P2_MAX_VALUE, P3_MAX_VALUE);
ConcurrentNavigableMap<KeyObject, Object> subview = table.submap(fromkey, toKey);
for (ConcurrentSkipListMap.Entry<KeyObject, Object> entry : subView.entrySet()) {
...
}
```

OR

```
KeyObject fromKey = new KeyObject(K1.P1, K1.P2, P3_MIN_VALUE);
KeyObject toKey = new KeyObject(K2.P2, K2.P2, P3_MAX_VALUE);
ConcurrentNavigableMap<KeyObject, Object> subview = table.submap(fromkey, toKey);
for (ConcurrentSkipListMap.Entry<KeyObject, Object> entry : subView.entrySet()) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use comparable or comparator interfaces and define the methods compareto or compare in them in the way to want them to behave.

Ajay